# Can there be multiple EPSPs with constant current injection to a neuron?

Tags: neuroscience, electrophysiology, action-potential

I am performing a current clamp experiment and measuring the change in membrane potential of a neuron with different current injections. A constant current of 50pA is injected to the neuron for 100ms. The current is not enough to cross the threshold for the neuron so there are no action potentials. But will the neuron have multiple EPSPs in this setup?

Comment: If you stimulate the soma you shouldn't get any EPSPs except for spontaneous but they'd have to be larger than the membrane depolarization you induced. You expect to see a step increase in membrane voltage.